# command to add permissions to a folder for a local user in windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, scripting, command-line-interface, user-management

as part of an installer I need to create a user with limited permissions

to add the user I will use

```
net user "<username>" <password> /add /fullname:"<username>"
```

I now need to explicitly add read and write permissions to a specific folder assigned for ftps for this user, how can this be done as part of a script that can be invoked by the installer? if at all possible I need to avoid adding additional dependencies like powerscript.

Comment: Try using ICACLS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ICACLS C:\FTPS_FOLDER /grant USERNAME:(OI)(CI)M`

will give you what you are after.

Comment: actually ICACLS C:\FTPS_FOLDER /grant USERNAME:(OI)(CI)RW but close enough

Comment: :) I figured you needed Modify instead of just read and write.